# Matplotlib PGF Greek Char

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode, plot, matplotlib

To include plots in Latex I use pythons matplotlib (v3.5.2). The plots are then exported as pgf so that they can be included in the latex document (with `\input...`). However, as soon as I use a Greek mu in a label, the export does not work. Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813797/matplotlib-and-unicode-characters) do not work, because matplotlib should support unicode by default now. I am thankful for any help!

Such approaches do not work:

```
plt.xlabel(u't in \u03bcs')
plt.xlabel('t in $\si{\micro \s}$')
```

Comment: Python 3 something (sorry I do not know) supports quite a lot of characters, could you try literally just putting μ in place of `\u` and such? Depending on your Python/Matplotlib version, using the literal "μ" should work, maybe with lualatex.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it does not work, and I would also not like to change from pdflatex, since my entire thesis was written with it and I do not know what the effects of this change would be.

Comment: When trying the example from https://timodenk.com/blog/exporting-matplotlib-plots-to-latex/ (using the plot from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/histogram_features.html) the mu appears without any problems with pdfLaTeX. There just `$\mu$` is used (full line is `ax.set_title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')`). Note the `r''` raw string, maybe that would work for you too?

Comment: @Marijn You're right, going back to that example was a good idea. Without using the SI package it works well.